Getting import error using vue3 component library created using vite
The .js library file have following import statement:
import JU, { defineComponent as Ge } from "vue";

Due to this I am getting below error:
SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue.js?v=44b28b6f' does not provide an export named 'default'

I have followed documentation correctly while creating a library. I am not sure how can I fix the import statement that is auto generated
I have followed below steps:https://ridaehamdani.medium.com/getting-started-creating-a-vue-3-components-library-with-vite-%EF%B8%8F-a670618dab54
I am getting above error on running host application where the library is used.

You are using default import from vue but vue provides named exports, you need to change the exports to named exports. Also if this does not solves your problem, then you need to share some code, so that it will be easier to help you.

The problem is import JU, which would be a "default import" because it's not in the brackets.
The error is telling you that Vue.js doesn't provide any default import, so juste remove the JU part
import { defineComponent as Ge } from "vue";


Thanks for the response. The file where we see this error is auto generated. I have checked the usage of JU inside the file, its used at one place. Code snippet:
We.mount(new Exe());
We.mount(VC, FC);
const Lxe = /* @PURE / Object.freeze(/ @PURE / Object.defineProperty({
proto: null,
MultiDrag: Pxe,
Sortable: We,
Swap: Dxe,
default: We
}, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: "Module" })), Nxe = / @PURE */ B3(Lxe);
(function(r, t) {
(function(n, i) {
r.exports = i(JU, Nxe);
})(typeof self < "u" ? self : He, function(e, n) {

Are you sure the library you use is compatible with your version of Vue?

Maybe create a GitHub issue on the library repository
